# Unable to use property from constructor

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm creating two ES js Classes (Person, Teacher)

```js
class Person {
    constructor (name = "no name") {
    this.name = name
}
```

Teacher inherit from Person

```js
class Teacher extends Person {      
    constructor(name, degree){
        super(name)
            this.degree = degree; 
    }
}
```

In the teacher constructor, I have a new property called degree.

when I create a new property called Full name that takes name and degree. Degree shows as undefined. Although when I log object teacher property is there. It looks like a delay issue. But, shouldn't I be able to access property right away?

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name = 'no name') {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Teacher extends Person {
  constructor(name, degree) {
    super(name);
    this.degree = degree;
  }

  fullname = this.degree + this.name;
  printFullName() {
    console.log(this.fullname);
  }
}

let person = new Teacher('Adam', 'MS.');

console.log(person);

person.printFullName(); // undefined Adam
```

https://repl.it/@adbarani/TrimBrilliantPaintprogram#index.js

Comment: there is no such field this.fullname    the field is called "name"

Comment: What makes you think that you can define something like `fullname` on the class like that? Are you intending to use something like a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)?

Comment: Full name is new field combination of name and degree

Comment: Just like I would define any other property in class that are not directly define in constructor @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: @trincot just added

Answer (score 1):

This is the behaviour specified in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#public_instance_fields):

> Public instance fields are added with `Object.defineProperty()` either at construction time in the base class (before the constructor body runs), or just after `super()` returns in a subclass.

Your code example is in the second case. The order of execution is thus:

1. Execute `super()` in case your class is a subclass
2. Define the public instance fields on `this`
3. Execute the rest of the constructor

If you need a work around, then don't define `fullname` with the field syntax, but assign to `this.fullname` as part of the constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

Update `fullname` to a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to compute the property value when it is accessed:

```
class Teacher extends Person {
  constructor(name, degree) {
    super(name);
    this.degree = degree;
  }

  get fullname() {
    return this.degree + this.name;
  };

  printFullName() {
    console.log(this.fullname);
  }
}
```

It sounds like you want fullname to be a property, why not set it in the constructor then?

```
class Teacher extends Person {
  constructor(name, degree) {
    super(name);
    this.degree = degree;
    this.fullname = this.degree + this.name;
  }

  printFullName() {
    console.log(this.fullname);
  }
}
```

Otherwise just change `printFullName` to do the work for you:

```
  printFullName() {
    console.log(this.degree + this.nam);
  }
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: So there's no way to do it as a property/field ?

Comment: If you are asking why `undefined` is also being logged out, it's because `printFullName` doesn't return anything, so basically it's doing `console.log(undefined)`

Comment: You can set it in the constructor. Otherwise when degree or name changes, you need to change fullname also. Or just have printFullName do the work of combining the values for you instead of referencing full name. There are different ways to solve this including the constructor, changing how printFullName works, or using a getter. Which do you prefer?

Comment: PrintFullName doesn't log undefine it print undefined + Adam, so only degree is undefined

Comment: Did you have a chance to get the JSFiddle i linked in a previous comment? You can see if prints `MS.Adam`.

Comment: Yes, still not as a property

Comment: It make sense to define in the constructor, I'll do that Thank you!